# getY() returning 0 upon adding a JComponent

Tags: java, swing, drag-and-drop

I'm new to Swing so I read through Java tutorials and API. I've been playing around with a subclass of `JComponent` (`DTPicture`-supports drag and drop). Basically I create a panel with a `GridLayout`. Then I populate the panel with `DTPicture` objects. `DTPicture` has inherited `getLocation()`. Upon calling this however, the value is 0. When I run the GUI however, I see `DTPicture` objects spanning vertically. So why is `getLocation` returning 0?

Thanks.

Below is my code:
*everything else has been initialized, declared, implemented.

```
public class RackBuilderTool extends JPanel{
    //maps rack slot # to DTPicture location on JPanel
    public static Point[] slotIDArray = new Point[42];

    public RackBuilderTool() {
    super(new GridLayout(42, 1));

       //DTPicture[] rackSlotArray = new DTPicture[42];
       for (int i = 0; i < 42; i++) {
            //add(new ComponentLabel());
           DTPicture temp = new DTPicture(null);
           System.out.println(add(temp).getLocation());
           //address of DTPicture Component
           slotIDArray[i] = temp.getLocation();

       }
   }
```

Comment: [This](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0240__Swing/HowtoUseGridLayout.htm) should aid your endeavors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Upon calling this however, the value is 0.

The size (and location) of a component defaults to 0 when a component is created.

> When I run the GUI however, I see DTPicture objects spanning vertically

The layout manager(s) are responsible for determining the size/location of a component. However, the layout manager is only invoked when you use `pack()` or `setVisible(true)` on a frame.

If you add a component to a visible frame, then you must use the revalidate() method to invoke the layout manager.

Think about it, the layout manager can't do its job until all components have been added to the panel since it will not know how to size every component. Especially in the case of a GridLayout all components are made the same size as the largest component. So how do you know what the largest component is until all components have been added? It would not be very efficient to do the layout every time a component is added.